# Google App Maker - Add a button for timestamp collection in the onclick method

Tags: timestamp, google-app-maker, error-messaging

I searched high and low and cannot find a specific answer that works. I need to add a button to a form in App Maker to record a timestamp, not a date, when clicked. So far the only thing that I've managed to get to work is

```
widget.datasource.item.Timestamp_OUT = new Date();
```

I've also tried

```
var timestamp = getTimeStamp();
```

But keep getting an error "ReferenceError: "getTimeStamp" is not defined". I'm probably missing the obvious as it shouldn't be this difficult to do something this simple. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have a function in your client scripts called function getTimeStamp(){}? If not, that would be why your error states getTimeStamp is not defined. I suppose if the first solution works for you, why don't you implement that one?

Comment: If you are working on client script, try this `var timestamp = + new Date()`;

Comment: If you need your timestamp to be in a specific format and that's what you're having trouble with, try looking into moment.js.

Comment: I've created the following function: --> function getTimeStamp() {
  var timestamp = + new Date();
} <--               and then updated the onlick to --> var timestamp = getTimeStamp();
widget.datasource.item.Timestamp_IN = new timestamp(); <-- but am now getting the error 'timestamp is not a constructor
at NewPage.Form1.Form1Body.Button1.onClick:2:39'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success! With the help of everyone here and the guys at this link: [Google Groups - Solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appmaker-users/wcV0fN5Yurc) I've managed to crack the case (and learn some stuff along the way).

Everything originally above works just fine if you take the " + " out of the function so it reads

```
function getTimeStamp(){
var timestamp = new Date();
return timestamp;
}
```

Then, onclick of

```
var timestamp = getTimeStamp();
widget.datasource.item.Timestamp_IN = timestamp;
```

Next, format the table to show the correct data with

```
@datasource.item.Test_Timestamp#formatDate('EEEE \x27at\x27 h:mm:ss a')
```

And "Hey Presto!" you get a button that, when clicked, gives you a timestamp. Thaks to everyone who pitched in, you're the reason people who are learning continue to do so and don't throw in the towel when things get difficult :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment:

You got almost everything right with a couple of exceptions. So your getTimeStamp function should look like this:

```
function getTimeStamp(){
    var timestamp = + new Date();
    return timestamp;
}
```

That is, because you have to return a value. The other problem is that when you are assigning the value to the datasource item, you don't have to use the keyword `new`; therefore, it should be like this:

```
var timestamp = getTimeStamp();
widget.datasource.item.Timestamp_IN = timestamp;
```

The above is basic javascript. I recommend you to dig into javascript before moving forward with appmaker.

Comment: Thats good advice, I'm busy learning and am challenging myself by building while learning. Everything there now comes back with no error regarding the formulae, but I still cannot get the button to do the job as I'm getting the error **Type mismatch: Cannot set type Number for property Timestamp_OUT. Type Date is expected.at NewPage.Form1.Form1Body.Button1.onClick:2:38 **, Though the field in the SQL table is Date, then changed SQL type to timestamp in the advanced setting. Seems its still expecting a date though?

Comment: @WayneStrydom I see, I started the same way. Good for you! Keep it up! I'd recommend you to change the SQL type of the field from date to number and handle the date conversion with javascript.

Comment: Thanks man, its a great challenge but learning a lot quickly. Your help so far has been greatly appreciated, its nice not being flamed for asking for help. Cheers!

Comment: could you maybe tell me why the timestamp here is locked to a specific timezone and not taking the time from the users device? Is there a way to change this?

Comment: @WayneStrydom It is not. Unless you are using the code in a server script. Server code is always bound to a time zone.