# How do I keep Google App Maker app from timing out

Tags: javascript, timeout, google-app-maker

This is a call for advice as I'm not sure how to tackle the brief issue I have. I've created a basic time-logging app in App Maker, link to previous notes on it here:

[Stack Overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829314/google-app-maker-add-a-button-for-timestamp-collection-in-the-onclick-method/54867905#54867905)

Attached here also is the main user interface (screenshot) to give an idea of how the user interacts with it:

[Gate Pass App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy9kg.jpg)

My initial issue is that the app is intended to log both the time the user logs out (to leave the workplace to run an errand) and the time in (when the user returns to the workplace). As the buttons timestamp when pressed, if the user is away for an extended period (a few hours) and the app is minimised, they cannot enter their return time on the same record.

I'm not sure if this is easily solved with some scripting, or the approach to how to the app is used is wrong for the app maker platform? Advice/help is most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I solved this over on the Google Groups page, link here [Google Groups - App Maker Users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appmaker-users/zwEruzuGTNY)