# Google App Maker timezone timestamp not using users device information

Tags: timestamp, timezone, google-app-maker

I've created an app in App Maker where I capture a timestamp of employee entries and exits from a site [Stack overflow project link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829314/google-app-maker-add-a-button-for-timestamp-collection-in-the-onclick-method) which works well except for two things:
(1) The time stamp is always to a fixed zone and not using the users device to log the date / time,
(2) I can't figure out how to automatically populate the users name based on their login information, and they are currently needing to type it in each time.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users email is the binding "@user.email" if that is allowed for your domain.